# How can I iterate more efficiently through dataframe and update one filed based on two columns value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to update one column in one dataframe with a value from a matrix (second dataframe). The value in the matrix has to be collected using two column values from the first dataframe.
The first dataframe has more than 30000 rows with data, and the matrix dataframe is a 613 row * 72 columns dataframe.

This is an extract of the code I'm using:

```
reference_data = reference_data[['Timestamp', 'Windspeed_avg', 'Power_avg', 'NacellePosition']]

cols = np.arange(0, 365, self.wdbin)
rows = np.arange(0, self.maxpower, self.pbin)

reference_data['col_id'] = pd.cut(reference_data['NacellePosition'], cols, include_lowest=True, right=False)

reference_data['row_id'] = pd.cut(reference_data['Power_avg'], rows, include_lowest=True, right=False)

df = reference_data.groupby(['row_id', 'col_id']).size().reset_index(name='Timestamp')

reference_data[colname] = 0

pref = pd.DataFrame()

for index, matrixbin in df.iterrows():
    rowmask = (reference_data['row_id'] == matrixbin['row_id'])
    colmask = (reference_data['col_id'] == matrixbin['col_id'])

    data = reference_data.loc[(rowmask & colmask), 'Power_avg'] * dfmatrix.at['%s' % matrixbin['row_id'], '%s' % matrixbin['col_id']])

    pref = pref.append(data)

reference_data[colname] = pref
```

This takes several minutes to compute and I have several files to calculate.

I there a more efficient way than iterating through all records?

Matrix dataframe extract:
[image]

```
index,"[0, 5)","[5, 10)","[10, 15)","[15, 20)","[20, 25)","[25, 30)","[30, 35)","[35, 40)","[40, 45)","[45, 50)","[50, 55)","[55, 60)","[60, 65)","[65, 70)","[70, 75)","[75, 80)","[80, 85)","[85, 90)","[90, 95)","[95, 100)","[100, 105)","[105, 110)","[110, 115)","[115, 120)","[120, 125)","[125, 130)","[130, 135)","[135, 140)","[140, 145)","[145, 150)","[150, 155)","[155, 160)","[160, 165)","[165, 170)","[170, 175)","[175, 180)","[180, 185)","[185, 190)","[190, 195)","[195, 200)","[200, 205)","[205, 210)","[210, 215)","[215, 220)","[220, 225)","[225, 230)","[230, 235)","[235, 240)","[240, 245)","[245, 250)","[250, 255)","[255, 260)","[260, 265)","[265, 270)","[270, 275)","[275, 280)","[280, 285)","[285, 290)","[290, 295)","[295, 300)","[300, 305)","[305, 310)","[310, 315)","[315, 320)","[320, 325)","[325, 330)","[330, 335)","[335, 340)","[340, 345)","[345, 350)","[350, 355)","[355, 360)"
"[0, 5)",1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
"[5, 10)",1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
"[10, 15)",1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
"[15, 20)",1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.9624484004127967,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.321594427244582,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0
"[20, 25)",1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.9746376811594202,1.2383549783549783,1.0,1.1672077922077921,1.154298418972332,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.7526785714285713,1.0,1.5282738095238095,1.8668478260869565,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.829604743083004,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,3.7098814229249006
"[25, 30)",1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.1307758620689654,1.3246021220159152,0.8191862518069415,1.0,0.8567414705345738,1.3924671008004343,1.0483611216369837,1.0,1.0,1.2705979537703675,1.3112290008841734,1.5214489214489215,0.6861263736263736,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.4574106634106634,1.0,1.5274725274725276
```

Data dataframe extract:
[image]

```
Timestamp,Windspeed_avg,Power_avg,NacellePosition,col_id,row_id,Pref1150054
2018-01-01 04:30:00,10.2,2755,229,"[225, 230)","[2755, 2760)",0
2018-01-01 04:40:00,9.6,2541,226,"[225, 230)","[2540, 2545)",0
2018-01-01 04:50:00,10.4,2936,228,"[225, 230)","[2935, 2940)",0
2018-01-01 05:00:00,10.2,2951,228,"[225, 230)","[2950, 2955)",0
2018-01-01 05:10:00,10.2,2906,227,"[225, 230)","[2905, 2910)",0
2018-01-01 05:20:00,9.3,2312,233,"[230, 235)","[2310, 2315)",0
2018-01-01 05:30:00,9.1,2142,232,"[230, 235)","[2140, 2145)",0
2018-01-01 05:40:00,10.9,3025,236,"[235, 240)","[3025, 3030)",0
2018-01-01 05:50:00,10.8,2991,230,"[230, 235)","[2990, 2995)",0
2018-01-01 06:00:00,11.2,3030,228,"[225, 230)","[3030, 3035)",0
2018-01-01 06:10:00,10.8,3030,224,"[220, 225)","[3030, 3035)",0
2018-01-01 06:20:00,11.4,3030,221,"[220, 225)","[3030, 3035)",0
2018-01-01 06:30:00,12.3,3030,227,"[225, 230)","[3030, 3035)",0
2018-01-01 06:40:00,12.4,3029,227,"[225, 230)","[3025, 3030)",0
2018-01-01 06:50:00,12.6,3029,227,"[225, 230)","[3025, 3030)",0
2018-01-01 07:00:00,13.2,3027,232,"[230, 235)","[3025, 3030)",0
2018-01-01 07:10:00,13.4,3030,232,"[230, 235)","[3030, 3035)",0
```

Comment: Could you post those pictures as actual text please? Also, your code's all indented... let me fix that for you.